# Usar mesmo algoritmo de ordenação com diferentes atributos

Tags: java, revisão-de-código

Cenário:

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação como tarefa do meu curso. Como a intenção do trabalho é justamente mostrar o que aprendemos durante as aulas, não posso fugir muito do que já tenho, melhor dizendo, não posso partir para "coisas muito avançadas". Embora eu saiba que naturalmente seja complicado de fazer o que eu pretendo, quero dicas de formas "simples" de fazê-lo.

Em determinado momento eu preciso ordenar uma coleção de usuários por suas vitórias (do maior pro menor), usando como **critério de desempate** suas derrotas (quanto menos derrotas, mais acima). A classe `Usuario` tem os dois atributos (`vitorias` e `derrotas`).

O que eu quero é fazer também a ordenação do *array* pela **quantidade de derrotas** do usuário, porém, sem precisar reescrever este método inteiro.

O meu método de ordenação atual é o seguinte (o algoritmo de ordenação usado é o [*bubble sort*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort))

```
private void ordenar(Usuario[] usuarios){
    boolean troca = true;

    while(troca){            
        troca = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < usuarios.length - 1; i++) {
            if(usuarios[i].getVitorias() < usuarios[i + 1].getVitorias() || 
               (usuarios[i].getVitorias() == usuarios[i + 1].getVitorias()
                && usuarios[i].getDerrotas() > usuarios[i + 1].getDerrotas()))
            {
                Usuario u = usuarios[i + 1];
                usuarios[i + 1] = usuarios[i];
                usuarios[i] = u;
                troca = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use uma interface

Uma das formas de você trocar a função de ordenação é através do uso de uma interface. Seguindo o código que você já escreveu, sem modificar a forma que você está fazendo o sort, uma sugestão de interface seria a seguinte:

```
interface Comparador 
{
    boolean compare(Usuario a, Usuario b);
}
```

Você poderia escrever duas implementações para ela, por exemplo:

Uma para ordenar pelas vitórias:

```
class Vitoriosos implements Comparador {
    public boolean compare(Usuario a, Usuario b) {
        return (a.getVitorias() < b.getVitorias() ||    
           (a.getVitorias() == b.getVitorias()
           && a.getDerrotas() > b.getDerrotas()));
    }
}
```

Outra para ordenar pelas derrotas:

```
class Derrotados implements Comparador {
    public boolean compare(Usuario a, Usuario b) {
        return (a.getDerrotas() < b.getDerrotas() ||    
          (a.getDerrotas() == b.getDerrotas()
          && a.getVitorias() > b.getVitorias()));
    }
}
```

A modificação no seu código seria para você passar, além da coleção de usuários, a instância da classe que implementa a interface. Ficaria algo como:

```
private static void ordenar(Usuario[] usuarios, Comparador cmp){
    boolean troca = true;

    while(troca){            
        troca = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < usuarios.length - 1; i++) {
            if(cmp.compare(usuarios[i], usuarios[i+1]))
            {
                Usuario u = usuarios[i + 1];
                usuarios[i + 1] = usuarios[i];
                usuarios[i] = u;
                troca = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No Java e em outras linguagens existe uma forma semelhante para criar classes de comparadores. No Java, a interface correspondente chama `Comparator`. [Nessa página](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) tem um tutorial bem simples explicando o `Comparator` e o `Comparable`.

Comment: Ótimo! Realmente parece uma saída muito boa e extremamente simples. Acho que faltou café hoje e eu compliquei o que não precisava. Valeu!

Comment: Tentei não modificar a linha que você já tinha começado.

Comment: Ficou bom demais, valeu novamente.

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde, conforme seu código, acredito que o modo mais simples de fazer o sort baseado em atributos seria mais ou menos desta maneira:

*Criar um enum para os campos que poderão ser ordenáveis*

```
public enum ESort {
    VITORIAS, DERROTAS;
}
```

*Criar um enum para o lado de ordenação*

```
public enum EOrder {
    ASCENDENTE, DESCENDENTE;
}
```

Criado estes dois enum's você vai precisar alterar seu método de ordenação para trabalhar com estas variâncias.

Agora você vai precisar criar um método que *valida a troca pela ordem*

```
public boolean isTrocaOrder(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, EOrder order) {
    if (order == EOrder.DESCENDENTE) {
        if (x1 < x2 || (x1 == x2 && y1 > y2)) {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (order == EOrder.ASCENDENTE) {
        if (x1 > x2 || (x1 == x2 && y1 < y2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Eu criei separadamente as *chamadas por campo*

```
private boolean isTrocaDerrotas(Usuario prev, Usuario next, EOrder order) {
    return isTrocaOrder(prev.getDerrotas(), prev.getVitorias(), next.getDerrotas(), next.getVitorias(), order);
}

private boolean isTrocaVitorias(Usuario prev, Usuario next, EOrder order) {
    return isTrocaOrder(prev.getVitorias(), prev.getDerrotas(), next.getVitorias(), next.getDerrotas(), order);
}
```

outro passo é criar um validador por campo

```
private boolean isTrocaCampo(Usuario prev, Usuario next, ESort sort, EOrder order) {
    if (sort == ESort.VITORIAS) {
        return isTrocaVitorias(prev, next, order);
    } else if (sort == ESort.DERROTAS) {
        return isTrocaDerrotas(prev, next, order);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Agora o seu método pode ser alterado

```
private void ordenar(Usuario[] usuarios, ESort sort, EOrder order) {
    boolean troca = true;

    while (troca) {
        troca = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.length - 1; i++) {
            Usuario prev = usuarios[i];
            Usuario next = usuarios[i + 1];
            if (isTrocaCampo(prev, next, sort, order)) {
                usuarios[i + 1] = prev;
                usuarios[i] = next;
                troca = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Acredito que desta forma você consiga reutilizar de várias maneiras seu método, exemplo de chamadas:

```
ordenar(usuarios, ESort.VITORIAS, EOrder.DESCENDENTE);
ordenar(usuarios, ESort.VITORIAS, EOrder.ASCENDENTE);
ordenar(usuarios, ESort.DERROTAS, EOrder.DESCENDENTE);
ordenar(usuarios, ESort.DERROTAS, EOrder.ASCENDENTE);
```

lembrando que este código está utilizando o método de ordenação bubble sort.
Caso você precise utilizar também outros métodos de ordenação você pode criar uma interface `ITipoOrdenacao` por exemplo com o método `sort` e alterar os métodos conforme a necessidade.

Espero ter ajudado 
Abraço

Comment: Boa! Gostei da solução.